# Is there any way to Call a Component on button Click in React JS?

Tags: reactjs

I am making a slot machine game and i wanted to display the emojis on button click  but the button is not working properly . I had also tried to display the component on the button click by passing emojis with the props but that was not working too.

```
import React,{Component} from 'react';
import '../App.css';
import SpGame from './SpGame.js';

const allowedEmoji=['','','','','','','','','']
var x=allowedEmoji[Math.floor(Math.random() * allowedEmoji.length)];
var y=allowedEmoji[Math.floor(Math.random() * allowedEmoji.length)];
var z=allowedEmoji[Math.floor(Math.random() * allowedEmoji.length)];
 class Sgame extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.sayHello = this.sayHello.bind(this);
  }

  sayHello() {

    if(x === y && y === z)
    {
                return (
                    <div className="background">
                        <hr/>
                            <h3>{x} {y} {z}</h3>
                            <p>Lucky! Match Found</p>
                            <hr/>
                    </div>
                );
    }
    else
    {
                    return (
                        <div className="background">
                            <hr/>
                                <h3>{x} {y} {z}</h3>
                                <p>UnLucky! Match Not Found</p>
                                <hr/>
                        </div>
                    );
    }

  }
   render(){
    
  return (
    <div>
      <div className="background">
        <div className="header">
        <h3> Slot Machine Game  </h3>
        <button onClick={this.sayHello}>Try Again</button>
        {this.sayHello}
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
  )
   }
}
export default Sgame;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't *call* components. React *renders* them for you. Also there is no point in returning jsx from an event callback as the return value of that callback is not evaluated or used by anything. A components render function describes what should be rendered given the current state of app.

What you need is component state. The current `x`, `y` and `z` values should be stored in the `state` object. Whenever the state changes the component re-renders. Your component should render the message according to the current values of `x`, `y` and `z`. When the button is clicked you set new random values in the state and react will call the render function again:

```
const AllowedEmojis = ["", "", ""];

// some helpers to generate a random pattern of emojis
const getRandomEmoji = () => (
  AllowedEmojis[Math.floor(Math.random() * AllowedEmojis.length)]
)

const getRandomPattern = () => ({
  x: getRandomEmoji(),
  y: getRandomEmoji(),
  z: getRandomEmoji()
});


class Sgame extends Component {
  // initialize the state with random pattern
  state = {
    pattern: getRandomPattern()
  };

  // called when the button is clicked
  // sets the state to 3 random new emojis
  handleShuffle = () => this.setState({ pattern: getRandomPattern() });

  render() {
    const { x, y, z } = this.state.pattern;

    // set the message according to the state of the current render
    const message = (x === y && y === z) ? "Lucky! Match Found" : "UnLucky! Match Not Found";

    return (
      <div>
        <div className="background">
          <div className="header">
            <h3> Slot Machine Game </h3>
            <button onClick={this.handleShuffle}>Try Again</button>
            <div className="background">
              <hr />
              <h3>{x} {y} {z}</h3>
              {/* render the message */}
              <p>{message}</p>
              <hr />
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Working example:
[image: Edit angry-edison-x2kdd]

Answer (score 0):

You have two possibilities here.

1. conditional rendering
2. set the component to show as a state variable

In the first case you need to add in the `render` method of the `Sgame` component i line like this:

```
return (
      ...
      {this.state.clicked ? <div> the html you want to show in case button is clicked </div> : null} 
      ...
      )
```

And you're `sayHello` implementation will be:

```
sayHello() {
   this.setState({ clicked:true })
}
```

But be sure to add the state variable in you're constructor:

```
constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.sayHello = this.sayHello.bind(this);
    clicked = null;
}
```

In this case once the button is clicked the `setState()` function will be called and the state update, consequently the component would be rerendered, the variable `clicked` will be true and the component in the ternary operator shown.
Be aware that to trigger a change in the DOM you need to pass through react lyfecycle, using the setState function.

Another possibility is that to set a state variable like this:

```
constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.sayHello = this.sayHello.bind(this);
    this.state = { componentToShowAfterClick : null };
}
```

in the render method of `sGame` you put `{this.state.componentToShowAfterClick}`. It would be null at a first render.
Then you modify you're `sayHello`, removing `return` and calling `setState(this.state.componentToShowAfterClick : <div>you're custom html here</div>)`

Comment: Storing react elements in component state is an anti-pattern. The state should contain plain serializable data types.

Comment: Yes you're right, it is however a working solution someone may find useful in particual case. But pay attention that as @trixn said it is an anti-pattern

Comment: Thanks for mentioning the methods. it is working correctly now

Answer (score 0):

There's couple of problem with your code

1. You are not updating value of `x`, `y` and `z` everytime the user click the try again button
2. You have to call the `this.sayHello` function in order to render the jsx code.

```js
import React,{Component} from 'react';
import '../App.css';
import SpGame from './SpGame.js';

 class Sgame extends Component {

  state = {
    x: null,
    y: null,
    z: null,
  }

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.allowedEmoji=['','','','','','','','','']
    this.sayHello = this.sayHello.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    // to set x, y and z value when the component mounts in DOM
    this.updateXYZ();
  }

  updateXYZ() {
    this.setState(
     {
       x: allowedEmoji[Math.floor(Math.random() * allowedEmoji.length)],
       y: allowedEmoji[Math.floor(Math.random() * allowedEmoji.length)],
       z: allowedEmoji[Math.floor(Math.random() * allowedEmoji.length)],
     }
    )
  }

  sayHello() {
    // on every attempt, update the x, y and z value
    this.updateXYZ();
    
    // destructure x, y and z from the state
    const {x, y, z} = this.state;

    if(x === y && y === z)
    {
                return (
                    <div className="background">
                        <hr/>
                            <h3>{x} {y} {z}</h3>
                            <p>Lucky! Match Found</p>
                            <hr/>
                    </div>
                );
    }
    else
    {
                    return (
                        <div className="background">
                            <hr/>
                                <h3>{x} {y} {z}</h3>
                                <p>UnLucky! Match Not Found</p>
                                <hr/>
                        </div>
                    );
    }

  }
   
 render(){
    
  return (
    <div>
      <div className="background">
        <div className="header">
        <h3> Slot Machine Game  </h3>
        <button onClick={this.sayHello}>Try Again</button>
        {this.sayHello()}
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
  )
   }
}
export default Sgame;
```